# Tkinter code runs slow sometimes and fast other times

Tags: python, performance, tkinter

Just a heads up I am *relatively* new to Tkinter.

I am working on a Tkinter GUI that is being used to interface with and run a separate program written in C++ that performs some experiments. The GUI allows the user to set up all the experiments, then run the experiments, and monitor them as they happen.

Right now I'm working on allowing the user to hide or show different sections of the GUI depending what they are currently working on. One section of the GUI consist of 72 buttons arranged in a grid, and the user can click any of the buttons to display some information that is pulled from a JSON file (when the program is loaded, not dynamically) that the C++ code uses to run.

The problem is that when I try to show the section with the 72 buttons it takes a long time to display the grid if done before the experiments are running. This is strange because when the experiments are running the grid appears nearly instantaneously. When it runs slow the GUI takes maybe 5 seconds to draw all 72 buttons and I can watch them all pop into existence one by one.

It is the exact same code that is being run both times. In both instances it is run on the same thread. I am actually only forgetting and re-packing the frame in which the buttons are contained, so its not like I am creating the buttons every time the section is reshown, I'm merely repacking the frame.

Unfortunately I don't really know what all of the code I should post for this issue because the GUI spans thousands of lines of code over numerous files... but as a start here is the direct code in question that either shows or hides this section of the GUI:

```
def showHideControlGrid(self):
    if self.grid_menu_var.get()==0:
        # The grid is currently being shown, so the user wants to hide it.
        self.control.GroupFrames[0].pack_forget()
        self.control.GroupFrames[1].pack_forget()
        if self.grid_menu_var.get() == 0 and self.movements_menu_var.get() == 0:
            #If both the grid and the movement controls are hidden then remove the middle section all together.
            self.midFrame.pack_forget()
    elif self.movements_menu_var.get()==0:
        # The grid is currently hidden, so the user wants to show it. The movement controls are also hidden so we must first repack the entire middle section again.
        self.rightFrame.pack_forget()
        
        self.midFrame.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.control.GroupFrames[0].pack(fill='x')
        self.control.GroupFrames[1].pack(fill='x')

        self.rightFrame.pack(fill=BOTH,padx=10,pady=10)
    else:
        # The grid is currently hidden, so the user wants to show it. The movement controls are currently displayed (meaning the middle section is packed) so we just need to re-pack the grid above the movement controls.
        self.control.GroupFrames[2].pack_forget()

        for w in self.control.GroupFrames:
            w.pack(fill='x')
```

Note that GroupFrames[0] and GroupFrames[1] contain the frames in which the grid is housed, and GroupFrames[2] contains the frame in which some movement controls are housed. But if the movement controls are shown they are always displayed beneath the grid.

Does anyone have any inkling into why the grid is so slow to draw sometimes and fast others?